# Height of NFC Reader Modal ActionSheet in iOS14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nfc

Using iOS14.0.1, Swift-5.3,

I try to find the height of the NFC-reader Modal ActionSheet.

Any idea on how to get it for all iOS devices ?

[image]